# WPF: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.IEventAggregator vs CLR event

Tags: wpf, prism

WPF: 
Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.IEventAggregator vs CLR event

Why should I use Prism's events? over good old CLR event/delegate?

Thanks

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample

Comment: there are better articles about eventAggregator. [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/455228/Design-Patterns-of-Behavioral-Design-Patterns#Mediator) explains pattern behind eventAggregator and its purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why should I use Prism's events? over good old CLR event/delegate?

Using ordinary CLR events will result in a tight coupling between the publisher of an event and subscriber. This tend to make an application harder to maintain. It could potentially also lead to memory leaks if a publisher lives longer than a subscriber and you forget to, or don’t know when to, unsubscribe from the event.

By introducing an event aggregator in between the publishers and subscribers, you can remove this tight coupling. The subscriber observes the event aggregator instead of the publisher and the publisher knows only about the event aggregator and not about the subscribers.

Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) blog post for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: because the sender and the receiver of the event do not need to know each other, just the type of the event and the event aggregator.

Long answer: see article in comments, as well as google and/or books...

Comment: [Thank you Haukinger] So, it's a little bit more loosely coupled than CLR events/delegates...